# How to reference the SKSpriteNode that's running an SKAction runblock?

Tags: objective-c-blocks, sprite-kit

I have a method that creates a random amount of SKSpriteNodes that are supposed to fall from the roof, sit on the ground a little while, then fade out. They need an SKPhysicsBody so they'll fall and bounce properly, but when I create a lot, it's using a lot of CPU, so I was trying to remove their physicsbody when they'd been sitting on the ground a little while.

I can't figure out how to use a runBlock to just say "do (blah) to the object calling this runBlock", is there a way?

```
for (int i=0; i < howManyDollars; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *bills = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bills.png"];
    int startX = arc4random() % (int)self.size.width/3;
    int startY = self.size.height;
    bills.position = CGPointMake(startX, startY);

    bills.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(bills.size.width/2, bills.size.height/2)];
    bills.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    [self addChild:bills];

    SKAction *wait1 = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.5];
    SKAction *wait2 = [SKAction waitForDuration:2];
    SKAction *removeDynamics = [SKAction runBlock:^(void) {
        // this is the spot I am confused at.
        //bills.physicsBody = nil;

    }];
    SKAction *fade = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:15];
    SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [bills runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait1, removeDynamics, wait2, fade, remove]]];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it already:

```
SKAction *removeDynamics = [SKAction runBlock:^(void) {
    bills.physicsBody = nil;
    NSLog(@"bills is: %@ (%p)", bills, bills);
}];
```

The cool thing about blocks is that they retain (copy) the objects in local scope. So if you create a block like the above and dereference the `bills` object, then for each block it will use the corresponding `bills` object that runs the action.

I've added the log statement so you can see for yourself that each block when executed is referencing a different object even though the variable name is the same and even though one would think based on the traditional sequential programming model that each `bills` object would have long been gone or referencing only the last object created.